# Validation framework in Struts

Tags: java, struts

Error/Exception:

> ValidatorResources not found in application scope under key "org.apache.commons.validator.VALIDATOR_RESOURCES

FrameWork: Struts1.2/Validation Framework

Jars Files Used:

```
commons-validator-1.3.1
commons-beanutils-1.8.0
commons-chain-1.2
commons-digester-1.8
commons-logging-1.0.4
```

All Inside LIB Folder

Configured in struts-config.xml

```
<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">     
  <set-property property="pathnames"       
       value="="/WEB-INF/validator_rules.xml,/WEB-INF/validation.xml" /> 
</plug-in>
```

Question: Where do I get "validator_rules.xml" file?

Answer (score 2):

[From the Struts documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.8/faqs/validator.html):

> By convention, the validators your application uses can be loaded through a file named "validator-rules.xml", and the validator forms (or "validations") can be configured separately (say, in a "validations.xml" file).

You get `validator-rules.xml` (not `validator_rules.xml`) from the Struts installation. Look inside searching for the proper name (with `-` not `_`).

The "src" archive is sure to contain it.